# Keyboard event affect other key pressed

Tags: linux, kde, keyboard, manjaro

Hi I am having a trouble with the keyboard in Manjaro KDE Plasma, when I press and hold one key, for example “A” everything works fine and the key keeps sending information that its pressed. Alright, but then when I keep that key pressed and just press and release other key for example “B”, “A” is no longer sending message that its pressed even though its, in fact, pressed. So i’m having the output of: “AAAAAAAAAAB” I want that output: “AAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAA…”

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Obs: this is not a keyboard hardware problem because "A" is being pressed in my mouse's side button and "B" is from actual keyboard

Comment: That's the way (traditional) keyboards work, physically. Have you seen different behavior with the same keyboard on a different operating system? Or with a different keyboard?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I have tried this on several softwares, and never seen a different behavior.